# Javascript strage scope behaviour

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

```
Name = 'window data';
document.Name = 'current document data';

(function(window, document) {
    var Name = 'local data';

    var myObj = {
        Name: 'object data',
        f: function() {
            alert(this.Name);
        }
    };

    myObj.newFun = function() {
        alert("Local scope " + Name + "\nObject Scope : " + this.Name);
    }

    function testFun() {
        alert("Window Scope : " + window.Name +
            "\nLocal Scope : " + Name +
            "\nObject Scope : " + this.Name +
            "\nCurrent document Scope : " + document.Name
        );
    }

    myObj.newFun();
    //testFun(); // Promts see "Object Scope : window data", but suppose to be "Object Scope : local data"
    // did not found the answer
    testFun.call(myObj);
    testFun.bind({
        Name: "name injected"
    })();

})(window, document);
```

I found a strange behavior when tried to call  testFun() inside the self executing anonymous block. I have added a comment beside the code whats actually happening and what i expected.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the context of `testFun` is `window`, so that behavior is perfectly normal (invoking `testFun()` will run it in the context of `window`). The line you have below, `testFun.call(myObj)` will result in the desired behavior (`call` calls a function using the first argument as context, or `this`).

Keep in mind you're in the self executing anonymous block (or immediate function)'s closure, which isn't the same as context. the context for any function not bound as a method to an object is always `window`, regardless of it's closure. it's closure however, is wherever the function is declared, so if you were to return the function at the end of your immediate one and assign it to a variable outside, `alert(Name)` would show `local data` and not `window data`, since testFun was declared in the closure where `Name` equals `local data`.

To further clarify:

```
// global closure scope, context (this) is window
Name = 'window data';
document.Name = 'current document data';

var testFun = (function(window, document) {
    // immediate closure scope, context is still window
    var Name = 'local data';

    var myObj = {
        Name: 'object data',
        f: function() {
            // myObj.f closure scope. immediate closure scope is available and superseeds global closure scope. context is myObj
            alert(this.Name); // 'object data'
        }
    };

    myObj.newFun = function() {
        // newFun closure scope. immediate scope available and superseeds global scope. context is myObj
        alert("Local scope " + Name + "\nObject Scope : " + this.Name); // outputs 'local data' (from immediate closure scope) and 'object data' (from myObj.Name)
    }

    function testFun() {
        // testFun closure scope. immediate scope available and superseeds global scope. context is window
        alert("Window Scope : " + window.Name + // 'window data'
            "\nLocal Scope : " + Name + // 'local data (from immediate scope)
            "\nObject Scope : " + this.Name + // 'window data' (remember this === window)
            "\nCurrent document Scope : " + document.Name // 'current document data'
        );
    }

    myObj.newFun();
    //testFun(); // Promts see "Object Scope : window data", but suppose to be "Object Scope : local data"
    // did not found the answer
    testFun.call(myObj); // context for testFun is changed to myObj **for this call only**, this.Name === 'object data'
    testFun.bind({
        Name: "name injected"
    })(); // context is the newly created object **for this call only**, this.Name === 'name injected'

return testFun;
})(window, document);

testFun(); // will output same as if called from within immediate function, because immediate scope survives immediate function's execution and is available to testFun (and superseeds global scope)

alert(Name); // 'window data' (global scope is still valid and is available to all statements declared outside immediate scope)
```

Comment: I think i understood a bit after reading your comment. The execution context of the self executing anonymous block is "window". As testFun() is not defined under any object, execution context of testFun() is also "window". As soon as i am doing testFun.call(myObj), it's execution context is "myObj". am i right?

Comment: you're welcome! a +1/correct answer would be much appreciated :)